# PHP. La última celda de mi tabla se muestra en blanco

Tags: php, html

Estoy imprimiendo los datos de una consulta a mi base de Datos MySQL usando este códigoID:

```
echo "<table>";
    echo"<tr>";
        echo"<th>Modelo</th>";
        echo"<th>Marca</th>";
        echo"<th> </th>";
    echo"</tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo"<tr>";
            echo'<td>' . $row["modelo"] . '</td>';
            echo'<td>' . $row["marca"] . '</td>';
            echo'<td> <a href="GuardaCambios.php?IdImpresora=' . $row["IdImpresora"] . '>Editar</a></td>';
        echo"</tr>";
    }
echo"</table>";
```

La tabla se muestra completa con los resultados esperados pero la última celda de la última fila siempre se muestra vacía, no importa cuántas filas se impriman, incluso si solo se imprime una fila la última celda siempre queda en blanco.

Comment: Te falta comillas dobles después del final del `href`, es decir `.. IdImpresora=' . $row["IdImpresora"] . ' "> ...`

Answer (score 0):

1.- Revisa la clausula WHERE de tu query, quizas el problema este ahi.

2.- Prueba cambiar el while por un for.

```
for ($count=0; $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); $count++)
{
  ...
}
```

Verificas cuantos registro trae la query con:

```
echo $count;
```